# Can no longer start virtual machine in VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

Whenever I try to start my VM in VirtualBox I get this error:

[image]

I tried rebooting my system and I still get the error. I didn't start any other VM programs.

I also have VMware Workstation installed on my computer which runs without problems.

Comment: Why are people saying this should be closed?

Comment: @Phenom, probably because it's not so much a programming question as an application support question. The votes are all to shift it accross to superuser, which is a more appropriate forum.

Comment: I was going to ask how to move it to SuperUser but I guess someone already did it for me.

Comment: I noticed that this problem occurs if I assign two CPU cores to the VM. If I assign only one CPU core then the problem goes away. However, I did not have this problem before using two CPU cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually get the same error on Ubuntu, which loads the kvm kernel module automatically, which conflicts with VirtualBox.

So you have to either blacklist the `kvm` module (and it's implementation module, which is `kvm_intel` for me), or rmmod both of them before starting your virtual machine:

```
sudo rmmod kvm_amd kvm
```

Answer (score 0):

This could mean that there is a lock file on disk that you need to delete. VMware Workstation has a similar warning but it allows you to start your VM if you are sure it's not used by anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

This means that VMWare is currently running and using the AMD-V virutalization extensions to the CPU. You need to completely shutdown VMWare in order to launch VirtualBox with the acceleration options enabled.